# Is it good thing to use `reduce(_ ## _) ` for IndexedSeq to UInt conversion in Chisel?

Tags: scala, reduce, chisel

For a little [Chisel project](https://github.com/Martoni/PimpMyCounter) I'm using reduce(_ ## _) function to convert an IndexedSeq to UInt.

```
class PdChain(n: Int = 4) extends Module {
  val io = IO(new Bundle {
    val count = Output(UInt(n.W))
  })
  // instantiate PdivTwo modules
  val pDivTwo = for (i <- 0 until n) yield {
    val pdivtwo = Module(new PDivTwo(i == 0))
    pdivtwo
  }
  val pDivTwo_io = VecInit(pDivTwo.map(_.io))

  // connect together
  pDivTwo_io(0).en := 1.U(1.W)
  for(i <- 1 until n) {
    pDivTwo_io(i).en := pDivTwo_io(i-1).p
  }

  val countValue = for (i <- 0 until n) yield pDivTwo_io(i).q

  io.count := countValue.reverse.reduce(_ ## _)
}
```

The value `countValue` is seen as `IndexedSeq` and `reduce()` operation convert it to `UInt`.

That works without error in my project.
But [I read that](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/scala-reduce-function/) `reduce()` function must be used on **commutative** operations.

Concatenation `##` operator **is not** commutative, then should avoid it here ?

Comment: I would suggest using `reduceLeft`. But also, Scala 2.13.13 will have some improved documentation on this topic: https://github.com/scala/scala/pull/10624

Comment: Thank ! on my Chisel project version I have no warning/error using `reduce()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to Seth-Tisue I have the answer : Yes I should avoid `reduce()`.

In this case, [`reduceLeft()`](https://www.scalawiki.com/wiki/ReduceLeft) should be used.